# Don't print code in Selenium HTML report

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

In HTML report when a test case fails I don't want the code to appear in the report, only the statements needs to be printed ([example of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJxaS.png)). Can anyone help me out here?

I am using Python 3.6, pycharm and generating HTML reports with the help of pytest-html.

Comment: yes you can write logic in try block

Answer (score 0):

Use try and except with in your code and may be include something like below

```
raise NoSuchElementException("An Error has been registered")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation under 'Modifying the results table'
https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html

It seems like you should be able to modify the output, which also includes removing. I would suggest trying this approach because the only requirement you have is not displaying the exceptions in the HTML output.

Avoid using try-except constructions in such a way that it suppresses the stacktrace in general, as this will make debugging failed test cases harder to do.